# Make ng serve on Angular 12 loads environment.ts instead of environment.prod.ts?

Tags: build, angular-cli

I read that Angular 12 changed some default configurations.
Now I'm not able to load **environment.ts** when starting the app with `ng serve`; **environment.prod.ts** is called instead.

I tried to load environment.ts typing `ng serve --configuration=development`, but **environment.prod.ts** is called again.

I edited the development property of **angular.json** this way, by adding the **fileReplacements** property and it works, but this seems a workaround to me and not the right solution:

```
 "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
```

Is there a better solution to start a development environment when running `ng serve`?